# SignalR not responding in MVC when script in a .js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr.client

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that uses SignalR.  It works fine when the client script that deals with SignalR is inline, but if I extract the scripts to a .js file it does not receive calls from the server.

```
@model LiveContentSample.Models.Entry

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details SignalR";
    ViewBag.EntryId = Model.Id;
}

<h2>Details with PartialView SignalR Comments</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Entry</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Content)
    </div>
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>

@Html.Action("_GetForEntryWithSignalR", "Comment", new { entryId = @Model.Id })
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
@*    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/CommentsSignalR.js"></script>*@
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var entryId = '@ViewBag.EntryId';
            var commentHub = $.connection.commentHub;

            commentHub.client.send = function (content) {
                $("#comments-list").append("<li>" + content + "</li>");
            };

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                commentHub.server.register(entryId);

                $("#add-comment").click(function () {
                    commentHub.server.addComment(entryId, $("#content").val());
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

But it does not work if I move the final script out to a .js file.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@ViewBag.EntryId` is a Razor directive. If you move your script into a JS file, Razor is no longer going to run anything. If you need to move this script to a separate file, you'll have to pass that entry ID into the script somehow.

Comment: Thank you @Jacob, I knew it was something simple.  Is there a standard way to pass the entryId?

Comment: I usually put a tiny inline script in the Razor that just calls a function in the external script, passing in the argument generated by Razor.